# uplifitng return value error reporting to Exceptions

Tags: c#, error-handling

In Framework Design guideline book there is a chapter about Exception and they talk about return-value-based error reporting and exception based error reporting and the fact that we in a O.O language like C# we should avoid return-value-based error reporting and use exceptions. With that in mind I was looking at our code that eight years ago was written in Visual Basic and last year with a automatic tool got converted to C#!

So here is a method I am looking at, I was wondering if the advice from that book applies to such a method and if yes, then what would be a better approach for rewriting this method?

```
public int Update(CaseStep oCaseStepIn)
{
    int result = 0;
    //Update the master object with the passed in object

    result = UCommonIndep.gnUPDATE_FAILED;
    if (Validate(oCaseStepIn) == UCommonIndep.gnVALIDATE_FAILED)
    {
        return result;
    }

    CaseStep oCaseStep = get_ItemByObjectKey(oCaseStepIn.CopyOfObjectKey);
    if (oCaseStep == null)
    {
        return result;
    }   

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw specific exceptions when possible.  Then, you **don't need a return value** in this case.

```
public void Update(CaseStep oCaseStepIn)
{
    //Update the master object with the passed in object
    if (Validate(oCaseStepIn) == UCommonIndep.gnVALIDATE_FAILED)
        throw new ValidationFailedUpdateException();

    CaseStep oCaseStep = get_ItemByObjectKey(oCaseStepIn.CopyOfObjectKey);
    if (oCaseStep == null)
        throw new KeyObjectNotFoundUpdateException();

    if (oCaseStep.Update(oCaseStepIn) != UCommonIndep.gnUPDATE_SUCCESSFUL)
        throw new UpdateFailedException();

    //*******************************
    //FYI - Insert code here to update any Key values that might have changed.
}
```

- UpdateFailedException extends Exception
- ValidationFailedUpdateException extends UpdateFailedException
- KeyObjectNotFoundUpdateException extends UpdateFailedException

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) as many opinions on exception handling as there are coders, but a good rule of thumb to start from is that exceptions should be thrown in exceptional circumstances.

So, is an update failure an exceptional occurrence?